# Regex for moving periods at end of sentences not abbreviations

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Looking for some ideas on how to remove the period character in sentences but not remove the periods in abbreviations.  For instance

`"The N.J. turnpike is long. Today is a beautiful day."`

Would be changed to:

`"The N.J. turnpike is long Today is a beautiful day"`

Comment: Def. abbr. and how to tell apart from periods.

Comment: This is very tough. Consider "The N.J. Turnpike is long. Today is a beautiful day." (Note the capital "T" in "Turnpike".) I don't think this can be handled with a regex; some semantic analysis will be required.

Comment: And how would you handle `Today I am in N.Y. Tomorrow I will be in N.J.`

Comment: As Ted suggests, this is pretty much an [AI-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete) problem.

Comment: This is a good argument for using two spaces after the period at the end of a sentence.  Semantically the same, displayed the same in HTML, but *much* easier to parse.

Comment: Why would you want to remove periods at the end of a sentence in light of abbreviations? Go BIG: remove all dots, or go NONE!

Comment: Actually I think I like the idea to remove all.

Comment: sln if you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to remove periods at the end of a sentence in light of abbreviations? Go BIG: remove all dots, or go NONE!

Answer (score 8):

This is a hard problem. [`Lingua::EN::Sentence`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua::EN::Sentence) makes a three-quarters assed attempt to solve it. It knows about common abbreviations in American English and has hooks for you to add other abbreviations you know about.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of the module. Would add an extra +1 for the phrase "three-quarters assed" if I could.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, this is a very difficult task in the general case.  If you want to learn more, you should start out by reading more about "sentence segmentation" or "sentence boundary disambiguation," which is the task of dividing a text into sentences.  Here's a few links to get you started:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation#Sentence_segmentation
- http://www.robincamille.com/2012-02-18-nltk-sentence-tokenizer/
- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html#sec-further-examples-of-supervised-classification
- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tokenize.html#punkt-tokenizer